# Displaying AJAX response in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I'm trying to append the contactTable with new rows for each ContactID and ContactName from my json response in a table. I am receiving data into the console but when I try to insert that data into my html document, I get a `undefined` value for each.

html result

```
<tr>
  <th id="contactName"></th>
  <th id="contactID"></th>
</tr>
 <tr>
   <td>undefined</td> 
   <td>undefined</td>
</tr>
```

index.html

```
 <table id="contactTable">
    <tr>
      <th id="contactName"></th>
      <th id="contactID"></th>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api2.******.com/crm/v1/rest/taggroups/1/contacts',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                drawTable(JSON.stringify(data));
                drawRow(JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log(data);
            // $('#contacts').html(JSON.stringify(data, null));  returns pretty json
            {alert('Success! Enjoy your data!')};
         }, 
        error: function () { alert('Request failed'); },
        beforeSend: setHeader
    });
});


function drawTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data[i]);
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#contactTable").append(row); 
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.ContactName + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.ContactID + "</td>"));
}

function setHeader(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ******');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
};
```

Here's the first record of the json response

```
Object
    TagMembers:Array(185)
        [0 … 99]
            0:
            ContactID:2732270
            ContactName:"First Last"
            RecAdd:"/Date(1427853954000-0700)/"
            RecAddUser:0
            RecID:3
            TagGroupID:1
```

Comment: Why stringify'ng it? Shouldn't it be e.g: `drawTable(data);` ?!

Comment: you shouldn't use `JSON.stringify(data)` but `data`, from what i see, your draw functions expect an object, with stringify you make it back to JSON string, while jQuery has already parsed the JSON to a ready-to-use object

Comment: Yes there should no JSON.Stringify

Comment: Also i think line 1 of drawTable should be for (var i = 0; i < data.TagMembers.length; i++) {

Answer (score 1):

your data looks something like this:

```
var data = {
    TagMembers: [
        {ContactID:2732270,
        ContactName:"First",
        RecAdd:"/Date(1427853954000-0700)/",
        RecAddUser:0,
        RecID:3,
        TagGroupID:4
        },
        {ContactID:2732275,
        ContactName:"Second",
        RecAdd:"/Date(1427853954000-0700)/",
        RecAddUser:0,
        RecID:4,
        TagGroupID:5
        },
        {ContactID:2732277,
        ContactName:"Third",
        RecAdd:"/Date(1427853954000-0700)/",
        RecAddUser:0,
        RecID:5,
        TagGroupID:5
        }]  
  };
```

This means you should send to `drowTable` function not `data` and not `JSON.stringify(data)`  (no need to convert object to string), but array of `data.TagMembers`: `drawTable(data.TagMembers);` so you can loop objects and get data form each one of them. 
And also no need to additional call to  `drawRow(JSON.stringify(data));`  it is redundant, becase your already calling to it inside `drowTable` function

Comment: I feel like I need more than data.TagMembers, but ContactName seperately?

Comment: But each object in array contains ContactName key. Try it with static data and you”ll see, your tds updated properly

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I neede to make some changes to `drawRow`

```
function drawRow(data) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#contactTable").append(row); 
    row.append($("<td>" + data.ContactName + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + data.ContactID + "</td>"));
}
```